# Finding differences between two shapefiles using shapely/fiona

Tags: python, shapely, fiona

I'm trying to find out whether there were any border changes between two yearly shapefiles. I've heard a lot of praise for Python's open source GIS tools like Shapely/Fiona, and thought I would try those, but I'm at a loss for how to go about implementing this.

Is Shapely poorly suited for this task?

Comment: What about using the [object.equals](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.equals) method?   What else have you tried?

Comment: Do you mean with "border changes" the extent of the shapefile?

Comment: @ustroetz - sorry, I should have explained better. Each shapefile is a map of school districts, and I want to see whether any of those districts change their borders between the two shapefiles. So it is not the extent of the shapefile, but rather each individual district's borders.

Comment: @Fezter - My understanding is that the object.equals method compares two polygons, but what I want is to compare a whole set of polygons to another set (see the clarification of my question above). But it's quite possible I'm misunderstanding something here.

Comment: What you could do is get all the vertices of the two shapefiles and compare them. If they are not identical, there were changes. Would that work?

Comment: @ustroetz - That sounds like it would work, I'll give it a try. The issue then is it doesn't seem like there would be an easy way to see where they differ. The ideal thing would be something equivalent to Shapely's difference() and intersection() functions, but applicable to whole shapefiles rather than individual polygons, if that makes sense. But it seems like such a thing does not exist?

Comment: Maybe you could provide two sample datasets (or an image), so we better understand what you want. I believe with Python GDAL you could write a script, that does something like that.

Comment: I think this R function would actually do what I want, maybe: http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sp/vignettes/over.pdf.

Comment: @ustroetz - The three images below should hopefully provide some clarification. The first shapefile is red, the 2nd is blue, and the third shows the difference/overlap (kind of). I'd like to identify how many instances occur where one shape changes (in this example, the answer would be 1). Or I'd like some output that shows the contrast like the example provided by gene below, but does it for the whole set of polygons. I need to investigate that R over package and see if that has what I need. 1: http://tinypic.com/r/2hnqubp/5, 2: http://tinypic.com/r/2ykiavq/5, 3: http://tinypic.com/r/spxkyp/5

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Suppose we have two polygons (green and blue):

[image]

They are not equal (as [Fetzer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/7424/fezter) suggest):

```
green.equals(blue)
False
```

and

```
blue.equals(green)
False
```

And we can can determine the [difference](http://toblerity.org/shapely/manual.html#object.difference) (in red):

```
blue.difference(green)
```

[image]

and

```
green.difference(blue)
```

gives an empty geometry

Thus, you can use a supplementary condition:

```
if not poly1.difference(poly2).is_empty:
     process
```

And if you want to find the nodes that have been modified:

```
 S1 = set(list(blue.difference(green).exterior.coords)
 S2 = set(list(blue.exterior.coords)
 S3 = set(list(green.exterior.coords)
```

S1 - S2 and S1 - S3 gives the points (two here blue and red):

[image]

and the distance:

```
point1.distance(point2)
```

### New : compare multiple polygons:

Here is one solution:
For that, I use [Fiona](http://toblerity.github.com/fiona/manual.html) to open the polygon shapefiles and save a resulting shapefile with differences:

[image]

```
import fiona
from shapely.geometry import shape
green = fiona.open("poly1.shp")
blue = fiona.open("poly2.shp") 
# test the function difference between green and blue shapefiles
[not shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])).is_empty for i,j in zip(list(green),list(blue))]
[False, False, False, True]
# control
for geom in [shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for i,j in zip(list(green),list(blue))]:
     print geom
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
POLYGON ((-0.0806077747083538 0.6329375155131045, 0.0085568963219002 0.5081069760707490, -0.0816567708381215 0.6025166277498414, -0.1529885076623247 0.5437728444828506, -0.1292856235630944 0.6206937720158269, -0.0806077747083538 0.6329375155131045))
# test the function difference between blue and green shapefiles
[not shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])).is_empty for i,j in zip(list(blue),list(green))]
[True, False, False, False]
# control
for geom in [shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for i,j in zip(list(blue),list(green))]:
    print geom
POLYGON ((0.2292711598746081 0.7386363636363635, 0.6691026645768023 0.6691026645768023, 0.2440830721003134 0.7205329153605015, 0.1074843260188087 0.3452978056426331, 0.2292711598746081 0.7386363636363635))
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
# thus you can write a resulting shapefile withe the differences
from shapely.geometry import mapping
schema = {'geometry': 'Polygon','properties': {'test': 'int'}}
with fiona.open('diff.shp','w','ESRI Shapefile', schema) as e:
     for geom  in [shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for i,j in zip(list(green),list(blue)]:
         if not geom.is_empty:
               e.write({'geometry':mapping(geom), 'properties':{'test':1}})
     for geom  in [shape(i['geometry']).difference(shape(j['geometry'])) for i,j in zip(list(blue),list(green))]:
         if not geom.is_empty:
               e.write({'geometry':mapping(geom), 'properties':{'test':2}})
```

Result:

[image]