# Python shapely difference between two polygons

Tags: python, shapefile, geometry, python-2.7, shapely

I have a geometry question using `shapely`,`Fiona` and polygons shapefiles with big data(over 700000 features any polygon shapefile).

```
polygon1.difference(polygon2)
```

I want to find the difference between two polygons using shapely (or maybe geopandas?) and I have read this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80090/finding-differences-between-two-shapefiles-in-python), I want the difference calculate only in the polygons segments(lines) and not the polygon geometry.

for example if I use code from the [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/80090/finding-differences-between-two-shapefiles-in-python) with add more lines the final export difference is a polygon layer,I want the line layer to show me the differences between two polygons.

[image: task]

with the light blue line is the difference.

that because I think is more fast the difference calculator to create lines from polygons.

Answer (score 5):

Once you've calculated the difference between your polygons (let's call this `delta`), take the difference between the exterior of `delta` and the exterior of your brown `polygon2`: `result = delta.exterior.difference(polygon2.exterior)`. Note that the sense of the difference will be significant and it may be tricky to generalize this to all possible polygons. Good luck!